# Is it acceptable to send an access token back to a browser client?

Tags: oauth2, access-token

I am currently following the instructions for getting an access token on behalf of a Twilio user described [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens)

[image]

The part that is confusing me where it seems to generate an access token then proxy it back to the client. I guess the idea is the access token is being made for the user on behalf of the application but that seems off to me. Is this a correct way to handle geting an access token to the browser? Are there limits to when you can pass back access tokens (besides ssl)? Shouldn't it be using a refresh token?

An example of how this works in practice see this example...

```
const token = new AccessToken(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
  process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
);
...
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  const identity = request.query.identity || 'identity';
  const room = request.query.room;
  response.send(tokenGenerator(identity, room));
});
```

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-access-token-server-node/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is acceptable.  The client needs to access some resource (in this case, a video chat room).  Your server verifies that the client has the appropriate permissions, and if so, it hands back a limited token that grants access to a specific resource.  If the client is not authorized, it refuses.  The client cannot access the resource without passing an authorization check.

This is effectively no different than issuing any other token credential, say, to your own API.  A refresh token is not needed here because the lifetime of the original token is intentionally limited (video meetings are usually relatively short) and if more access is needed, the client can make another request to get another token, at which point its permission to access will be checked again.  Effectively, your session management is acting as the overarching access control here, and the Twilio token allows access to a specific portion of whatever the user could normally access.

It is absolutely required that you use TLS in this case, including for the authentication stage.  Otherwise, an attacker can replay previously seen login credentials and steal tokens.  TLS is always required for security when passing bearer credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the token!

Some access tokens (e.g. the ones from many OAuth flows) are *specifically intended* for use by the client (usually browser). They are unique to (and sometimes uniquely identify) a particular user, and any access charges or usage quotas are deducted for that user specifically. They typically require that the user have completed an authorization process, and are short-lived (typically a JWT with a short lifetime, optionally plus a revocable refresh token). The authorization process may require the use of an OAuth client secret (or similar), which the user (browser, etc.) must never see, but once the server completes the flow it can hand off the token to the client.

An example here might be an access token for a social media site/service, which allows a third-party app to post content to the social media site as the authorized user. Unless the third-party app has special permissions for some reason, there's no reason to keep this token secret from the user, since the user could just as well go interact with the social media site directly rather than via the third-party app.

Other access tokens are specifically intended for use only by trusted back-end systems. They might be associated with a particular user but in many cases they aren't; the user is instead a field that the back-end sends along with the token-bearing request. Their access permissions and charges / quota usage are instead from the perspective of the "app" (e.g. OAuth client), not the user (or user agent, such as a browser). They may have heightened permissions and/or long lifetimes compared to a token that is specific to a user. Tokens of this kind that are persistent (indefinite lifetime) are often called "API keys", but not all tokens of this sort are persistent.

An example of this kind might be an access token for requesting that a third-party service send an SMS to a specified number. This token should never be exposed to the user, because then the user could use it to send SMS that the app owner would have to pay for and be held responsible for. Instead, even if the app wants to allow the user to send custom messages (rather than e.g. the app server just using the service to push its own messages to users), the user would need to send the desired message to the app server, which would then relay it to the third-party SMS service with the token now attached (and the app server would need to take care of limiting how much an individual user uses).

---

Given the diagram here, it seems clear that the token is the first kind, intended for use by the user directly. The exact behavior of the "Twilio Helper Library" is unspecified; the token might be minted locally within the app server, or by Twilio in response to a call that the library makes.

However, it's reasonable to be skeptical! There's no indication that Twilio would know or care who the user is; the app might provide some identifying information, but it's most likely not enough for Twilio to either charge the user or hold them responsible for token misuse. Given that, users could potentially try to abuse the token in a way that would make trouble for the app. Since you're presumably the app developer, it's reasonable to not want to permit this!